# Can I access Team Foundation Server 2010 without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

1. Do I need VS installed in order to connect to TFS?
2. If I'll download ONLY [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329) without VS, will I get some UI (similar the one I get in VS) to connect to TFS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Team explorer installs a Visual Studio shell, so you get the same GUI as if you had VS installed. In addition you get tf.exe which allows you to do all source control functions from the command line.

Comment: Bear in mind that you'll still need a CAL if you're going to modify any information on the TFS database. A Visual Studio licence comes with a CAL already, but Team Explorer does not.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you do not need VS to connect to TFS. TFS also provides web based interface to manage TFS.
2. Once Team Explorer is installed, you get access to the TF.EXE command line tool, but also worth looking at the TFS Power Toys for the tftp.exe command line tool and the PowerShell Snapin for more command line operation.

Comment: No, its a command line tool. For visual client, you will need VS

Comment: Actually, if you have Visual Studio, Team Explorer installs into that.  If you do not, then Team Explorer includes the Visual Studio shell to provide its own UI client.